# Android AAR + Intent Filter: clarification

Tags: android, nfc, intentfilter, ndef, android-applicationrecord

Based on this documentation available at [Android NFC doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html):

> If a tag contains an AAR, the tag dispatch system dispatches in the
>   following manner:
>
> 1. Try to start an Activity using an intent filter as normal. If the
>      Activity that matches the intent also matches the AAR, start the
>      Activity.
> 2. If the Activity that filters for the intent does not match
>      the AAR, if multiple Activities can handle the intent, or if no
>      Activity handles the intent, start the application specified by the
>      AAR.
> 3. If no application can start with the AAR, go to Google Play to
>      download the application based on the AAR.

From those lines I understand that if I specify an intent filter for an activity `A` and the received NDEF message matches the filter of `A`, `A` will be started even if the NDEF message contains the AAR record of the app that `A` belongs to.

In my case `A` starts only if there is no AAR record. As soon as I add the AAR record, the activity `A` is not started: when the NDEF message is detected, the main activity of the app indicated in the AAR is launched.

What do they mean with "*if the Activity [...] also matches the AAR*"?

Is there anyone who can provide a hint?

Answer (score 9):

> 1.) Try to start an Activity using an intent filter as normal. If the Activity that matches the intent also matches the AAR, start the Activity.

This means that activity A has an `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent filter **that matches the datatype** of the **first** NDEF record of the NDEF message on the tag **and** that the AAR matches the application package name that activity A belongs to.

> 2.) If the Activity that filters for the intent does not match the AAR, if multiple Activities can handle the intent, or if no Activity handles the intent, start the application specified by the AAR.

This means that there is

- an activity A with an `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent filter that does not match the datatype of the **first** NDEF record of the NDEF message on the tag **and** that the AAR matches the application package name that activity A belongs to,
- an activity A and an activity B that both have an `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent filter **that matches the datatype** of the **first** NDEF record of the NDEF message on the tag **and** that the AAR matches the application package name that activities A and B belong to, or
- no activity of the app matching the AAR has an `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent filter.

In that case, the app that has a package name that matches the one in the AAR is started by sending intent action `MAIN` with category `LAUNCHER` for the first activity in your app that has such an intent filter. Hence, the app is "started" as if the launcher icon for that activity was clicked.

> 3.) If no application can start with the AAR, go to Google Play to download the application based on the AAR.

This means that if there is no app with a package name that matches the one in the AAR, then Play Store is opened.

---

So, for instance, if you have the NDEF message

```
+------------------------------+----------------------+
| URI: http://www.example.com/ | AAR: com.example.app |
+------------------------------+----------------------+
```

then you would need an application with the package name `com.example.app` that has one activity with an intent filter like

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" android:pathPrefix="/" />
</intent-filter>
```

Scenario 1 (match for activity A):

```
<manifest package="com.example.app" ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <application ...>
        <activity android:name="MAIN" ...>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="A" ...>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" android:pathPrefix="/" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Scenario 2a (no match for activity A, MAIN is launched):

```
<manifest package="com.example.app" ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <application ...>
        <activity android:name="MAIN" ...>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="A" ...>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Scenario 2b (match for activities A and B, MAIN is launched):

```
<manifest package="com.example.app" ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <application ...>
        <activity android:name="MAIN" ...>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="A" ...>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" android:pathPrefix="/" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="B" ...>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" android:pathPrefix="/" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Scenario 2c (no `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent filter, MAIN is launched):

```
<manifest package="com.example.app" ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <application ...>
        <activity android:name="MAIN" ...>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer: I will read it carefully as soon as I can.

Comment: If your specified activity does not start, but instead MAIN is launched, check the order of your records.
Answer already states, but still gave me bit of trouble, as I overlooked that part. Do NOT put the AAR as first record.